# How to create triggers in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to sharepoint. I have a requirement to create a trigger for every document created in a documentation library. I have a documentation library and for every folder added to this library (not for the subfolders inside each of these folders) the trigger should get activated and should create an item on a list which is maintained in an other subsite. Is this doable?

Thanks and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutly doable. What you are looking for is called Event Receiver.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tschareck !! Will explore in this area.